# Flask markdown2: how to render all HTML tags but escape <script> tag

Tags: python, flask, markdown

My users will be able to enter the markdown text to be rendered on the website. The problem is when I do this:

```
# filter
def md_to_html(text):
    return markdown2.markdown(text)

<div>
   ${content | md_to_html | safe }
</div>
```

it renders HTML properly but unfortunately, it also renders the script code. It I remove "safe" filter it will not render at all.

How to render only HTML escaping Javascript code?

Comment: seems like `safe` escapes all html? what you want is to have a whitelist of html tags that will be left alone. I don't know Flask, but something like BeautifulSoup or html-sanitizer does this.